# How Offline.js works

Tags: javascript, offline.js

I'm trying to use offline.js, but i don't understand how to control the result if a server is up or down  [Offline.js git](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/)

My idea is like this:

```
var result = function checkServer(){
Offline.options = {checks: {xhr: {url: 'https://www.google.com/'}}};
   if(offline.options == true){
     return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Huh? What are you trying to do?

Comment: my idea is to check if a page like google.com is online or not with using offline.js and if is online return true if not return false. ;)

Comment: You can't do that because of the SOP.  But that has nothing to do with offline.js anyway; you should just use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks `Offline.on(event, handler, context)` then you know if you are online or offline. See docs: http://github.hubspot.com/offline/